# TF model palindrome number but this model returning loss== nan for each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow import lite
 
 
#101 == str.rev("101")
inp= np.array([101, 23332, 4554, 1111, 2345, 3662, 8786745745365333], dtype=float)
op= np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=float)
 
 
model= keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1,input_shape=[1]),
                         keras.layers.Dense(units=1,input_shape=[1])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(inp, op, epochs=1000)
 
 
print(model.predict([2288]))
```

code I have created, please tell me what I am doing wrong
Tf version 2.3.0

Comment: your target is binary, so your loss function should be binary cross-entropy rather than mse which is used for a regression problems.

Comment: Also, the last layer should have a `sigmoid` activation function since you are performing binary classification.

Answer (score 0):

As rightly mentioned by @M.Innat and @Kabilan Mohanraj, you should use binary crossentropy and last layer should have `sigmoid` activation function

Working code as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras 
 
inp= np.array([101, 23332, 4554, 1111, 2345, 3662, 8786745745365333], dtype=float)
op= np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=float)
 
 
model= keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1,input_shape=[1], activation='relu'),
                         keras.layers.Dense(units=1,input_shape=[1],activation='sigmoid')])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(inp, op, epochs=10)
 
print(model.predict([2288]))
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 0.6931
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6931
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6930
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6930
Epoch 5/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6929
Epoch 6/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6929
Epoch 7/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6928
Epoch 8/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6928
Epoch 9/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6927
Epoch 10/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6927
[[0.5017657]]
```